# Bava Metzia: Dual meaning of "Metzia"

Tags: bava-metzia

Has anyone ever commented on the fact that Bava Metzia, literally the "middle gate," can also mean the gate of "found things," and Bava Metzia is the one masechta that deals with finding lost objects?

Comment: are you asking whether there is discussion of the pun connecting the Aramaic word and the Hebrew word?

Answer (score 4):

They sound alike in English but I'm afraid there's nothing more to it.

The tractate's name is מציעא,
which is Aramaic for  אמצע (middle). Mem-tzadi-'ayin. It goes between "Bava Kama" (first portion of civil law) and Bava Basra (last portion).

Lost objects occupy the first part of Bava Metzia, but are not its sole (or even main) topic.

"Finding" is mem-tzadi-aleph; just because most Ashkenazim pronounce 'ayin and aleph interchangeably doesn't mean the letters are linguistically identical.